# Can't set Combobox SelectedItem, Value

Tags: c#, combobox, foreach, selecteditem, selectedvalue

In my application I have a customer who can have multiple locations. 
When you select a customer in my dropdownbox, it will load comboboxes in a flowlayoutpanel with all it's locations.

This is my code for this:

```
        IEnumerable<locatie> opstapPlaatsen = Database.getOpstapplaatsen(klant.klant_id);

        foreach (locatie opstapplaats in opstapPlaatsen)
        {

            if (opstapPlaatsen.Count() <= 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                ComboBox cbbOpstap = new ComboBox();
                cbbOpstap.Width = 200;
                cbbOpstap.Height = 20;

                cbbOpstap.DataSource = Database.getLocaties();
                cbbOpstap.ValueMember = "locatie_id";
                cbbOpstap.SelectedValue = opstapplaats.locatie_id;
                cbbOpstap.SelectedItem = opstapplaats;
                cbbOpstap.DisplayMember = "FullAdress";

                flpOpstapplaats.Controls.Add(cbbOpstap);
            }
        }
```

My problem is that I can't set the SelectedItem or/and Value. When I look with breakpoints there is a value in `opstapplaats.locatie_id` (the correct one), but `SelectedValue` stays `null`.

I do something alike outside of a loop, and for a combobox not created in code, and it works there.

[image: Alike code, but working]

I have no idea what's causing this? Is this because it's in a foreach, because I used it before out of a foreach and then it worked.

Comment: Does assigning the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` before setting the `DataSource` make any difference ?

Comment: Just tried it, nothing changed. Thanks though! :)

Comment: Not related to the problem but `opstapPlaatsen.Count() <= 0` conditional check is not required i think since it will not be in the loop in the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out you have to first add the control to the panel, and then set the `ValueMember`, `DisplayMember`...

```
ComboBox cbbOpstap = new ComboBox();

cbbOpstap.Width = 200;
cbbOpstap.Height = 20;

flpOpstapplaats.Controls.Add(cbbOpstap);

cbbOpstap.ValueMember = "locatie_id";
cbbOpstap.DisplayMember = "FullAdress";
bbOpstap.DataSource = LocatieManagement.getLocaties();  

cbbOpstap.SelectedValue = opstapplaats.locatie_id;
cbbOpstap.SelectedItem = opstapplaats;
```

Then it works, I hope this can help somebody!

Comment: By the way it has to be in that same order, i.e. If first you set the ValueMember, DisplayMember and DataSource and then you add the control to the form (which is what I was trying to do since my combo is filled dynamically from different tables and it may not find the source) you won't be able to set the SelectedValue.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `Valuemember` and `displayMember`, please use `SelectedIndex` to select an item.

```
cbbOpstap.DataSource = Database.getLocaties();
cbbOpstap.ValueMember = "locatie_id";
cbbOpstap.DisplayMember = "FullAdress";
cbbOpstap.SelectedIndex = cbbOpstap.Items.IndexOf(opstapplaats.locatie_id);
```

Comment: The code works, but it also doesn't change the SelectedIndex, it's still always at the default (-1). I have made [a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/QzbyR.png) of the problem, to clarify.

Comment: Are you sure that there is an item with the value opstapplaats.locatie_id in the dropdown?

Comment: @ThomasSchoof Just check if the value you are passing is in the same case as in the `Items` list.

Comment: There appear to be no items in the combobox, but the datasource is filled! [Here](http://i.imgur.com/5y631.png) you can see the filled datasource, I'm not sure what's causing this?

Comment: is it a webapplication or windows application?

Comment: I do exactly the same thing out of the `foreach` (to just get the adress) and there it just works. http://i.imgur.com/5g4RR.png